# Texture Painting Showing Triangle Shapes

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

When painting on my surface, I am getting weird shapes that show the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What can I do to make the surface smoother and not jagged with the painted textures?

Comment: Does this effect also occur when flood filling with a solid color?

Comment: @CraigDJones Yes, even with a solid color it shows the shape. Even though the topology is flat. It does not do it in all areas.

Comment: Assuming you have already checked for 'remove doubles' and don't have any faces overlapping by accident, I would turn on face masking and try only painting the faces that are offending with another image and then see if going back to paint all then gets you the same problem.